# Create Byte array from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, arrays

I want to create a Byte Array like this one;

```
   Byte UUID[] = {0xEB, 0xEF, 0xD0, 0x83, 0x70, 0xA2, 0x47, 0xC8, 0x98, 0x37, 0xE7, 0xB5, 0x63, 0x4D, 0xF5, 0x24};
```

But the problem here I am facing is, I need to fill all the elements in the above array programatically from a `NSMutableArray` that holds the values as below;

```
(
    0xEB,
    0xEF,
    0xD0,
    0x83,
    0x70,
    0xA2,
    0x47,
    0xC8,
    0x98,
    0x37,
    0xE7,
    0xB5,
    0x63,
    0x4D,
    0xF5,
    0x24
)
```

I have tried with the integer values of each index but it is showing '/0' in the Byte Array.
If anyone have any information regarding this please share.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get this array of numbers?

Comment: Share your current code to give some context

Comment: i am creating this array from a string. Now i want to place each value of this array into the byte array.

Comment: Suppose, This is my byte array     Byte UUID[16] = {};

Comment: Now i want to add the below sixteen values into it, from this array    (
    0xEB,
    0xEF,
    0xD0,
    0x83,
    0x70,
    0xA2,
    0x47,
    0xC8,
    0x98,
    0x37,
    0xE7,
    0xB5,
    0x63,
    0x4D,
    0xF5,
    0x24
)

Comment: Where do you get HEX-encoded string? May be you should use Base64-encoded string? It's shorter and `NSData` have suitable methods to work with Base64-encoded strings.

Comment: What is the result of `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([[array firstObject] class])` where `array` is your `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: This is the output for the array: ( 0xEB, 0xEF, 0xD0, 0x83, 0x70, 0xA2, 0x47, 0xC8, 0x98, 0x37, 0xE7, 0xB5, 0x63, 0x4D, 0xF5, 0x24 ). Initially it was without '0x' as the prefix. i just appended it to the begininnig to serve my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have an array of *strings* "0xEB", "0xEF", ..., the following should work:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"0xEB", @"0xEF", @"0xD0", @"0x83", @"0x70", @"0xA2", @"0x47", @"0xC8", @"0x98", @"0x37", @"0xE7", @"0xB5", @"0x63", @"0x4D", @"0xF5", @"0x24"];
Byte UUID[16];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    UUID[i] = strtoul([array[i] UTF8String], NULL, 16);
}
```

This works even if the strings do not have the "0x" prefix:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"EB", @"EF", ...]
```

because `strtoul(string, ..., 16)` reads a string with or without "0x" prefix
in base 16, and converts it to an integer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am getting this; (Byte [16]) UUID = {
  [0] = '\xeb'
  [1] = '\xef'
  [2] = '\xd0'
  [3] = '\x83'
  [4] = 'p'
  [5] = '\xa2'
  [6] = 'G'
  [7] = '\xc8'
  [8] = '\x98'
  [9] = '7'
  [10] = '\xe7'
  [11] = '\xb5'
  [12] = 'c'
  [13] = 'M'
  [14] = '\xf5'
  [15] = '$'
}

Comment: @MohitManhas: Yes, and that is *correct*. `Byte` is the same as `unsigned char`, and that is how the debugger prints the values. You get exactly the same result as with `Byte UUID[] = {0xEB, 0xEF, 0xD0, 0x83, ...};`. For example '\xeb' is a char with the code 0xEB, and '7' is the character with the code 0x37.

Comment: @MohitManhas: You are welcome! - Please note that you can "accept" the answer if it helped by clicking on the *check mark*. That marks the problem as closed and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer. (I am mentioning this because you have never accepted an answer so far.)

Comment: i know that, i will accept it once the problem is resolved at my end.